# Set HTML label to WebService invocation's result

Tags: html, xml, web-services

Rather new to webservices when it comes to implementing them in HTML. I've been doing research on this for, no joke, an entire month, and still found nothing. Here's the code - The idea is it's just a simple email sender from a fixed email address, and the webservice is called directly from the form.

```
    <body>
    <form id="mainForm" method="post" action="http://habakkuk/api/emailHandler.asmx/SendEmailMain"">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="textcolumn">
                    To:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" size="50" name="m_To"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="textcolumn">
                    Subject:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" size="50" name="m_Subject"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="messageText">
                    Message:
                </td>
                <td class="messageBox">
                    <textarea name="m_Body" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="textcolumn"></td>
                <td>
                    <input type=submit value="Send Message">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <p>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>
</body>
```

Thing is, even this bit took me a week's worth of searching, to add to the ridiculousness. Now my issue is getting the [webservice result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MW9G.png) to set the text of a label or something somehow. Preferably, I'd want an alert, though as far as I am aware, that's a javascript bit and I'm not sure how to go about that either.

Any pointers, assistance, or references to an already answered question I may have missed will be of major help.

Comment: do you have any code that represents the pass or fail of the webservice?

Comment: You mean an error catcher? No, I don't, I didn't implement it because I'm not doing this for a permanent purpose, but rather I'm experimenting and trying to get myself more into this part of coding.